# Using ZURB Foundation for tooltips -- Newly-created DOM elements are not bound to tooltip 'hover' event

Tags: tooltip, zurb-foundation

My specific usage case is that I'm using a .net postback to display an update panel of elements that have tooltips associated with them.  I have already initialized the ZURB Foundation (provides tooltips) script on the page, and the first-page tooltips work great.  After the postback, I want to *re*initialize the script so that these new tooltip items are bound to the 'hover' event.

Generic usage case is any situation where new tooltip-enabled elements are added in any way.

It appears to me that the 'hover' binding is done on page init to the *existing* collection of  '.has-tip' elements, but there is handling of *future* .has-tip elements coming into existance.

I'd like to do the following:
a) Reinitialize the tooltip plugin and search for new .has-tip elements to attach the 'hover' event to.

have tried a number of different ways to try and reinitialize, but

```
$.fn.tooltips('init');
```

seems to be the most hopeful, in that it successfully calls the init method in the script, but does not bind the hover event to the new .has-tip elements.

Comment: I don't have your answer, but I can tell you that the plugin creates elements at the bottom of your page. These are the tool tips which are displayed on hover. You might want to try looking in the code to see when the actual binding happens.

Answer (score 1):

Edit/Clarification:

1. it seems like there was a bug with dynamic content: 
   https://github.com/zurb/foundation/pull/465
2. <s>When the bug is fixed
   (you can fix it yourself, read the pull req. for more info),</s> the bug is fixed, so you can
   trigger a page-wide tool-tip refresh with:

   $(document).tooltips('reload');

---

Original answer

If you didn't figure it out yet, jquery.tooltips.js has a method/function called .reload that actually seems to be the most promising (code is from the foundation plugin):

```
reload : function() {
      var $self = $(this);
      return ($self.data('tooltips')) ? $self.tooltips('destroy').tooltips('init') : $self.tooltips('init');
    },
```

It's really just a chain of their other methods, but it's probably best to .destroy before .init to avoid double tooltips or some other collision.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a lot of suggestions, but what truly works is:

After you finish editing the DOM, you have to call to

```
$(document).foundation();
```

This sentence is going to refresh everything, including your tooltips. WORKS LIKE A CHARM.

Comment: Gives you warnings in your console if you already have $(document).foundation() being called else where.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when genereted modal windows with Ajax,

Here is my fix for that:

```
$(document)
  .on('opened.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
    $('html').css({'overflow': 'hidden'});
    $('.has-tip').each(function(i){
    var tip = $(this);
    Foundation.libs.tooltip.create(tip);
  });
})
```

It works for ZF v5.2+